# Third-order dispersion of glass

Tags: optics, dispersion

When working with short laser pulses, it is important to compensate the dispersion of a pulse passing through a material because it changes the pulse's shape. The effect of dispersion can be described as a phase of the pulse's spectrum, which makes it possible to identify different orders of dispersion by expanding this phase as a Taylor series. Then the different orders can be treated separately.

In the near-infrared, the second order of dispersion (or group delay dispersion) of glasses can have both positive and negative sign, so different glasses can be used to compensate each others' effects. On the other hand, the third order of dispersion always seems to have a positive sign. According to a paper by Schmidt et al. (Appl. Phys. Lett. 96, 121109, which can also be found at http://www.attoscience.ca/femtopubs.htm), this is even true for all glasses in their entire transmission range.

I'm just wondering why this should be true for all glasses. Is there something fundamental about the third derivative of the refractive index of transparent materials?